# Error with big number of characters while making a letter pyramid

Tags: c++

The task is to make a letter pyramid. I have done it but its behaviour goes very strange after I pass a certain number of characters that were inputed. Looking forward to an answer.

```
string input{};
string reverseString{};

getline(cin,input);

for(int j = input.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
        reverseString += input.at(j);
    }

for(int i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
    int numberOfSpaces {};
    numberOfSpaces = input.length()-i;
    string spaces(" ",numberOfSpaces);

    cout<< spaces << input.substr(0,i) << input.at(i)<<reverseString.substr(numberOfSpaces,i) <<spaces<<endl;

}
```

This is an example of the input/output:

[image]

Comment: when you `cout`, dont use `+`, instead use `<<`.

Comment: The question is very unclear. What is it exacly?

Comment: Also what Is 'osnova'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string spaces(" ",numberOfSpaces);`

This doesn't do what you think it does.

This constructor takes an array and a count.

It copies count (in this case `numberOfSpaces`) items from the passed in array.

The passed in array has length 1 (technically 2 with the null terminator), and so anything > 2 will cause undefined behaviour as it reads off the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks, instead used a for loop to do the thing that i have tried doing with that constructor. Used number of spaces as the limit in my for loop instead.